# Inflate nested layout in Koltin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have a Constraint layout which 2 main elements inside it: a nested scroll view with a list of elements defined inside another layout file and a textview used as a footer.
This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/menu_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".sections.main.menu.MenuFragment">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_title"
                style="@style/AppTheme.TextTitle1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/mid_small_margin"
                android:text="@string/menu_title"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <include layout="@layout/list_item_menu_fragment" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_title_2"
        style="@style/AppTheme.TextTitle1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/mid_small_margin"
        android:text="@string/menu_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the `list_item_menu_fragment.xml` layout defined in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menu_elements_list"
    style="@style/RectangularTextViewMenu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/mid_small_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/menu_item_profile"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/links_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/charge_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/menu_pay_charge"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_charge"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/pay_online_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/menu_pay_online"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_pay_online"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my fragment:

```
class MenuFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentMenuBinding? = null
private val menuViewModel by viewModels<MenuViewModel>()

private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

If I tryo access to my list of elements using `binding.chargeButton` it says that i cannot do it (because it is in another layout). If I do `binding.menuTitle` it works perfectly. How can I access to those elements?

Answer (score 5):

As written in [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

> An instance of a binding class contains direct references to all views
> that have an ID in the corresponding layout.

You have to assign an ID to the included layout and then you can call it from the parent view binding class.

Change from

```
<include layout="@layout/list_item_menu_fragment" />
```

to

```
<include android:id="@+id/listItemMenu" layout="@layout/list_item_menu_fragment" />
```

Now you can call `binding.listItemMenu.chargeButton`